# How to identify terms from list in unseen documents

Tags: python, nlp, information-retrieval

Given a list of predefined terms that can be formed by one, two or even three words, the problem is to count their ocurrences in a set of documents with a free vocabulary (ie, much many words).

```
terms= [
[t1],
[t2, t3],
[t4, t5, t6],
[t7],...]
```

and the documents where this terms needs to be recognized are in the form of:

```
docs = [
[w1, w2, t1, w3, w4, t7],        #d1
[w1, w4, t4, t5, t6, wi, ...],   #d2
[wj, t7, ..] ..]                 #d3
```

The desired output should be

```
[2, 1, 1, ...]
```

This is, the first doc has two terms of interest, the second has 1 (formed of three words) and so on.

If the terms needed to be accounted for where 1 word length, then I could easily order each document alphabetically, remove repeted terms (set) and then intersect with the terms of size 1 word. Counting repeated words are the searched result.

But with terms of length >=2 things get tricky.

I've been using gensim to form a bag of words and detect the indexes when using a new phrase

e.g.

```
dict_terms = corpora.Dictionary(phrases)

sentence = unseen_docs[0]
idxs     = dict_terms[sentence]
```

And then count the seend idxs considering if the indexes are sequential, that would mean that a single term has been seen and not 2 o 3 of them.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scikit-learn ( a very popular Python package for Machine Learning) has a Module that does exactly what you're asking:

Here's how to do it:

First install sklearn

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Now the code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3))

#Given your corpus is an iterable of strings, or a List of strings, for simplicity:
corpus = [...]

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

print(X)
```

The output is a matrix of size m x n. E.g:

```
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]
```

**Columns** represent words, **lines** represent documents. So for each line, you have the resulting bag of words.

But how to retrieve which words appear where? You can get each "column" name, by using:

```
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

You'll get a list of words (the words are organized alphabetically).

Now, suppose you want to know the number of times that each word appears in your corpus (not on a single document).

The matrix you receive as output is a "numpy" (another package) array. This can be easy flattened (sum all lines) by doing:

```
import numpy as np #np is like a convention for numpy, if you don't know this already.

sum_of_all_words = np.sum(X, axis=0)
```

That'll give you something like:

```
[[1 4 2 4 1 1 4 1 4]]
```

The column order is the same for the words.

Finally, you can filter the terms from your dictionary by doing:

```
dict_terms = corpora.Dictionary(phrases)
counts = {}
words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for idx, word in enumerate(words):
   if word in dict_terms:
      counts[word] = sum_of_all_words[0, idx]
```

Hope this helps!

Read more about CountVectorizer here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer

(Also, give a look on TFIDFVectorizer, if you're using bag of words, tf-idf is a huge upgrade in most cases)

I also recommend you to take a look at this page for feature extraction with sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html